# Android: Help on Optimal Size of the Splash Screen Image

Tags: android, splash-screen

I need to know the optimal size for the splash screen image. Since different phones support different resoltions, how do I set the size of my splash screen image (PORTRAIT), and how to scale it to fit in different resolutions? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the three folders - drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi and provide three images with desired dpi.

Comment: Can you tell me the desired dpi or pixel for those

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this one - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?